# После комадны mv /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1.bak не загружается OpenWrt

Tags: linux, openwrt

Установил OpenWrt на Xaomi Mi Router 3. Хотел поставить пакет python-pip, но получал ошибку "`check_data_file_clashes: Package libgcc1 wants to install file /lib/libgcc_s.so.1`"
После поиска ошибки наткнулся на совет в ветке гитхаба, где говорилось про что команда помогла"

```
mv /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1.bak && \
    opkg-install coreutils-timeout
```

"
Однако, после перещемения файла lib/libgcc_s.so.1, все последующие команды возвращали ошибку (будь то `mov`, `opkg install` и тд.). Вернуть файл обратно не получилось. После перезагрузки роутера он перестал загружаться вовсе (вечно мигает светодиод). ssh тоже не работет. Доступа к роутеру нет никакого. 
Я так понимаю можно покупать новый роутер?

Comment: Вы не переместили файл, а переименовали его. Чтобы вернуть обратно - `mv /lib/libgcc_s.so.1.bak /lib/libgcc_s.so.1`

Comment: @Denis640Kb После того как я переименовал файл, практически любые команды, в том числе и mv уже не работали. Я пытался переименовать его обратно. А после перезагрузки, и доступ к SSH тоже пропал, ибо роутер более не загружается.

Comment: ресет  роутера не помогает, и доступа к админки нет через провод?

Comment: Точных деталей сего роутера не знаю, но по симптомам осмелюсь предположить, что прошивка убита и теперь остаётся только разбирать роутер, подпаиваться к UART, включать в загрузчике TFTP и перепрошиваться

Answer (score 1):

Удалось восстановить прошивку через UART